# How to run Python from MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to run Python from MATLAB, but when I try I got the message:

```matlab
py.list({'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday'})
```

> Unable to resolve the name py.list.

I also have tried pyenv

```matlab
pyenv
```

```
ans = 

  PythonEnvironment with properties:

          Version: "3.7"
       Executable: "C:\Users\Familia\.conda\envs\matlab\python.exe"
          Library: "C:\Users\Familia\.conda\envs\matlab\python37.dll"
             Home: "C:\Users\Familia\.conda\envs\matlab"
           Status: NotLoaded
    ExecutionMode: InProcess
```

Could be my problem the Status? NotLoaded? How can I change that for Loaded?
Since this path is with Conda, I also tried to change for another Python version I have installed without
Anaconda, with this command:

```matlab
pe = pyenv('Version','C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe')
```

> Error using pyenv
> Path argument does not specify a valid executable.

How can I overcome that?

Comment: @dubbbdan: That's not valid MATLAB syntax.

Comment: See possible problems and solutions in the MATLAB documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/undefined-variable-py-or-function-py-command.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo  I have tried the suggestions in the link, but still, the same problem, when I use pyenv I got the error: Path argument does not specify a valid executable.

Comment: Jennifer: In particular, have you verified that your MATLAB program is 64-bit and your Python program is also 64-bit? You likely have a 32-bit version of Python installed at that location (if it is there at all).

Comment: @CrisLuengo you're right the version of python was 32bit. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are seeing that error because the path you specified is not valid.

Open a Command prompt window and type:

```
where python
```

this will return a list of locations of Python installations on your machine. On my machine, the command returns:

```
C:\Users\paolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
```

so we can use this location when calling `pyenv` in MATLAB:

```
>> pyenv('Version','C:\Users\paolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe')
```

then I can use `py.list`:

```
>> py.list({'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday'})

ans = 

  Python list with no properties.

    ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
```

Comment: I have tried that, and the error  I have when I do what you explained is : Error using pyenv
Path argument does not specify a valid executable.

Comment: What's the output of `where python`?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me by using the path from a created conda environment exclusively having python 3.7 for Matlab 2021a. So the steps were:

1. conda create --name matlabpy python=3.7 #You can give any name to the env
2. Add the path where this "matlabpy" environment is located by clicking in "Set Path" in Matlab
3. Run py.list({'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday'})

Hope it works for you as well

Answer (score 0):

I manage to overcome that uninstalling python and installing again the 64bit, and during the installation, I chose to add python to the path environment and install for all users. That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For people working on a network where the MATLAB you are using is installed on another users account you need to share your user's folder with the account that MATLAB is installed on.

Steps:

1. go to `C:\Users` and right click on the folder with your username
2. go to the `Sharing` tab and click `Share...`
3. click on the arrow next to `Add`, and select `Find people...`
4. Search for the user that owns the MATLAB you're using and select it from the search results, then `OK`
5. Restart MATLAB